# Iterating through all possible Boolean values

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, boolean

I have a function like this:

```
fun foo(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, c: Boolean) { /*...*/ }
```

and I wanted to test it with all possible argument values:

```
for (a in false..true)
    for (b in false..true)
        for (c in false..true) {
            val expected = ...
            assertThat(foo(a, b, c)).isEqualTo(expected)
        }
```

But unfortunately Kotlin doesn't have a BooleanRange type.

I can do this instead:

```
for (a in 0..1)
    for (b in 0..1)
        for (c in 0..1) {
            val expected = ...
            assertThat(foo(a == 1, b == 1, c == 1)).isEqualTo(expected)
        }
```

But this is not at all clear.

I can do this:

```
for (a in arrayOf(false, true))
    for (b in arrayOf(false, true))
        for (c in arrayOf(false, true)) {
            val expected = ...
            assertThat(foo(a, b, c)).isEqualTo(expected)
        }
```

But this is still too verbose. Is there a neater way, maybe Kotlin has a function that iterates directly through the two values false and true? I see that it has a `BooleanIterator` type, but I'm not sure if that's any use here.

Comment: I think `arrayOf(false, true)` is just fine. You can always create a: `val allBools = arrayOf(false, true)` and then reuse it.

Comment: I honestly feel the verbosity here results in clearer code than using Bitsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers (upvoted). In the end, I took broot's comment and settled for:

```
val allBooleans = booleanArrayOf(false, true)
for (a in allBooleans)
    for (b in allBooleans)
        for (c in allBooleans)
            foo(a, b, c)
```

Although if I wanted it to be shorter, I could have done this:

```
for ((c, b, a) in (0..7).map { BooleanArray(3) { i and (1 shl it) != 0 } })
    foo(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

A low tech approach using pre-calculated `Triple`s may be more readable:

```kotlin
    val allBooleanTriples = listOf(
        Triple(true,  true,  true ),
        Triple(true,  true,  false),
        Triple(true,  false, true ),
        Triple(true,  false, false),
        Triple(false, true,  true ),
        Triple(false, true,  false),
        Triple(false, false, true ),
        Triple(false, false, false),
    )

    allBooleanTriples.map {
        val (a, b, c) = it
        // val expected = ...
        // assertThat(foo(a, b, c)).isEqualTo(expected)
    }
```

This code is not succinct, but is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions would work just fine. Following is an alternative, but might not be fathomable. Using verbose code for clarity is helpful for smaller number of parameters. While using `BitSet` to get all combinations of boolean values, we can extend to any number of boolean values.

```
(0 until 8L).map {
  BitSet.valueOf(longArrayOf(it))
}.map {
  assertThat(foo(it[0], it[1], it[2])).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

Instead of looping through all the possible values, you can use `@ParamerterizedTest` and move boolean combination logic out of actual test. You get the test output with all combinations, helps debugging issues with test parameters.

```
 companion object {
  private val expected = arrayOf(...)
  @JvmStatic fun provideInput() : Stream<Arguments> {
   return (0 until 8).map {
     val b = BitSet.valueOf(longArrayOf(it.toLong()))
     Arguments.of(b[0], b[1], b[2], expected[it])
   }.stream()
  }
 }

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("provideInput")
fun test(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, c: Boolean, expected: Boolean){
  assertThat(foo(a,b,c)).isEqualTo(expected)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had never thought of using BitSet for this!

Comment: It's a pity BitSet is not destructurable so I can't do `val (a, b, c) = BitSet...`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate though all binary numbers from 0 to 111 (three ones by number of arguments) and check corresponding bits:

```
repeat(8) { n ->
    foo(n and 1 == 0, n and 2 == 0, n and 4 == 0)
}
```